# How to create a Skype meeting from Outlook appointment using Python?

Tags: python, outlook-addin

Skype for Business 2016 is installed and sign in. Outlook 2016 is installed with Skype Meeting Add-in. There is "Skype Meeting" icon when new an appointment.
[image]
I'm using Python win32com library to create appointment. I want to ask how to create a Skype meeting from appointment using Python? Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The button belong to an external COM add-in. The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. The best what you could do is to execute the button programmatically using the [ExecuteMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso) method of the `CommandBars` class. This method is useful in cases where there is no object model for a particular command. Works on controls that are built-in `buttons`, `toggleButtons`, and `splitButtons`. But the `Skype Meeting` button is not a built-in one. So, the last resort is to use UI Automation to execute it programmatically. Read more about that in the [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) section.

Microsoft Active Accessibility is a Component Object Model (COM)-based technology that improves the way accessibility aids work with applications running on Microsoft Windows. It provides dynamic-link libraries that are incorporated into the operating system as well as a COM interface and API elements that provide reliable methods for exposing information about UI elements.